# Is non-local return in Scala new?

Tags: scala, return, control-flow

A colleague just showed me this and I was surprised that it compiled at all:

```
def toUpper(s: Option[String]): String = {
  s.getOrElse(return "default").toUpperCase
  //          ^^^^^^  // a return here in the closure??
}
```

and this even works:

```
println(toUpper(Some("text"))) // TEXT
println(toUpper(None))         // default
```

I thought `return` from inside a closure was not allowed. Since when has this worked? Are there caveats with such non-local returns?

Comment: Very confusing, since neither `Some("text").getOrElse(return "default").toUpperCase` nor `None.getOrElse(return "default").toUpperCase` compile.

Comment: `def foo(): String = Some("text").getOrElse(return "default").toUpperCase` compiles fine; so does `def foo(): String = (None: Option[String]).getOrElse(return "default").toUpperCase`.

Comment: @Alexey Sure, but it does not if you drop the `def foo():String =` part.

Comment: @agilesteel The error message says there needs to be an enclosing method to return to.

Comment: I don't see anything confusing about that. `return` in Scala always returns from the enclosing method; if you aren't inside a method definition, you can't use `return`.

Comment: @Kipton Barros That makes sense. I just assumed, that since the parameter of `getOrElse` is by name (meaning that a block of code can be passed is), the `return` might refer to this block and not to the enclosing method. But apparently it is not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The semantics are relatively simple: `return` will throw a `NonLocalReturnControl` that is caught at the enclosing method, `toUpper`. It doesn't look like a recent feature; there is no mention of `return` in the [Scala change-log](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43) since version 2.0.

Here's the relevant description from the Scala Language Spec, section 6.20:

> Returning from a nested anonymous function is implemented by throwing
>   and catching a scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnException. Any exception
>   catches between the point of return and the enclosing methods might
>   see the exception. A key comparison makes sure that these exceptions
>   are only caught by the method instance which is terminated by the return.
>
> If the return expression is itself part of an anonymous function, it
>   is possible that the enclosing instance of f has already returned
>   before the return expression is executed. In that case, the thrown
>   scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnException will not be caught, and will
>   propagate up the call stack.

Here's an example in which the `NonLocalReturnControl` escapes:

```
var g: () => Unit = _
def f() { g = () => return }
f() // set g
g() // scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl$mcI$sp
```

Comment: Thanks for the information! Looks like it's actually a `NonLocalReturnControl` that's thrown and caught.

Comment: @Kipton How can the situation, "enclosing instance of f has already returned" arise. Can you give and example?

Answer (score 6):

It's been allowed since forever, more or less. It might look strange there, but there are many places where the reverse would be true. For example:

```
// excessive use of braces for the sake of making scopes clearer

def findFirst[A](l: List[A])(p: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
    for (x <- l) {
        if (p(x)) return Some(x)
    }
    None
}
```