# Why return in getOrElse makes tail recursion not possible?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I am confused by following code: the code is artificial, but still I think it is tail recursive. The compiler does not agree and produces an error message:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def listSize(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  if (l.isEmpty) {
    None.getOrElse( return s )
  }
  listSize(l.tail, s + 1)
}
```

How is the code above making tail recusion not possible? Why is the compiler telling me:

> could not optimize @tailrec annotated method listSize: it contains a recursive call not in tail position

A similar code (with `return` inside of `map`) compiles fine:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def listSize(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  if (l.isEmpty) {
    Some(()).map( return s )
  }
  listSize(l.tail, s + 1)
}
```

Even the code obtained by inlining `None.isEmpty` compiles fine:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def listSize(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  if (l.isEmpty) {
    if (None.isEmpty) {
      return s
    } else None.get
  }
  listSize(l.tail, s + 1)
}
```

On the other hand, code with slightly modified map **is** rejected by the compiler and produces the error:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def listSize(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  if (l.isEmpty) {
    Some(()).map( x => return s )
  }
  listSize(l.tail, s + 1)
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling the compiler can't decide wether or not your method is tail recursive because of the return statement, probably he's being defensive and telling you that the recursion is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because the `return` in your first snippet is a non-local one (it's nested inside a lambda). Scala uses exceptions to compile non-local `return` expressions, so the code gets transformed by the compiler from this:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def listSize(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  if (l.isEmpty) {
    None.getOrElse( return s )
  }
  listSize(l.tail, s + 1)
}
```

To something *similar* to this (compile with `scalac -Xprint:tailcalls`):

```
def listSize2(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  val key = new Object

  try {
    if (l.isEmpty) {
      None.getOrElse {
        throw new scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl(key, 0)
      }
    }

    listSize2(l.tail, s + 1)
  } catch {
    case e: scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl[Int @unchecked] =>
      if (e.key == key)
        e.value
      else
        throw e
  }
}
```

The last point is that recursive calls are not tail calls when wrapped in try/catch blocks. Basically, this contrieved example:

```
def self(a: Int): Int = {
  try {
    self(a)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => 0
  }
}
```

Is akin to this, which is obviously not tail-recursive:

```
def self(a: Int): Int = {
  if (self(a)) {
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

There are certain particular cases where you can optimize this (down to two stack frames, if not one), but there doesn't seem to exist an universal rule to apply to this kind of situation.

Also, the `return` expression in this snippet, is not a non-local `return`, which is why the function can be optimized:

```
@annotation.tailrec
def listSize(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  if (l.isEmpty) {
    // `return` happens _before_ map `is` called.
    Some(()).map( return s )
  }
  listSize(l.tail, s + 1)
}
```

The above works because, in Scala, `return e` is an expression, not a statement. Its type is `Nothing`, though, which is a subtype of everything, including `Unit => X`, which is the type required by map's param. The evaluation though is pretty simple, `e` is returned from the enclosing function before `map` is even executed (arguments are evaluated before the method call, obviously). It may be confusing because you'd expect `map(return e)` to be parsed/interpreted as `map(_ => return e)`, but it's not.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain in more detail how is `map( return s )` processed? I had some strange feeling about it before, but still I do not get exactly what it does - why is compiler accepting it, and how does it match expected map signature, which should be Unit => X?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost surely a bug with the compiler, or a partially implemented feature.

It most likely has to do with the implementation of `return` in an expression in Scala.  Non-local `return` statements are implemented using exceptions, so that when the `return` is called, a `NonLocalReturnException` is thrown, and the whole expression is wrapped in a `try-catch`.  I bet `x => return x` is converted to a nested expression, which, when wrapped in a `try-catch`, is confusing the compiler when determining if it can use `@tailrec`.  I would go so far as to say that using `@tailrec` in conjunction with non-local `return` should be avoided.

Read more about the implementation of `return` in Scala in [this](http://dev.bizo.com/2010/01/scala-supports-non-local-returns.html) blog post or in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915701/is-non-local-return-in-scala-new) question.

Answer (score 0):

`return` always breaks recursion calls. You should change you code into something like this:

```
@tailrec
def listSize(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  l match {
    case Nil => s
    case head :: tail => listSize(tail, s + 1)
  }  
}
```

Comment: In your own example you can replace `case Nil => s` with `case Nil => return s` and the function will still be compiled as tail recursive?

Comment: Yes, because for tail recursion last call should be `return` or `next call the same function`. In your code , `return` isn't in the last step. Your `return` is alternative for val assigment and then (in the next step) is eventually recursive call.

Comment: I am afraid I still do not see the reason. :( How is `return` in `getOrElse` different from return in e.g. `Some(()).map( return s )`, or in the `getOrElse` which is inlined? Also, are there some links listing the requirements you mentioned: " last call should be return or next call the same function"?

Comment: I have added some more examples. What is the difference between the two `map` variants? Why `map( return s )` compiles and `map( x => return s )` does not?

Answer (score -1):

I can't try it out right now, but will this fix the problem?

```
@annotation.tailrec
def listSize(l : Seq[Any], s: Int = 0): Int = {
  if (l.isEmpty) {
    None.getOrElse( return s )
  } else {
    listSize(l.tail, s + 1)
  }
}
```

Using `if-else`, instead of just `if` will insure the `if` statement always return something.

Comment: I have tried it and this is rejected by the compiler as well.