# How to return nothing from an else block of an IF Condition in scala?

Tags: java, scala, short-circuiting

I am working on migrating a Java project to Scala and encountered the below code:

```java
private void searchClauses( TCustomSqlStatement select ) {
    if ( !searchInClauses.contains( select ) ) {
        searchInClauses.add( select );
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
    if ( select instanceof TSelectSqlStatement ) {
        TSelectSqlStatement statement = (TSelectSqlStatement) select;
        HashMap clauseTable = new HashMap( );


        if ( statement.getWhereClause( ) != null ) {
            clauseTable.put( ( statement.getWhereClause( ).getCondition( ) ),
                    ClauseType.where );
        }

        for ( TExpression expr : (TExpression[]) clauseTable.keySet( ).toArray( new TExpression[0] ) ) {
            ClauseType type = (ClauseType) clauseTable.get( expr );
            searchExpression( expr,
                    select,
                    type == null ? null : type.name( ) );
            searchTables( select );

        }
    }
}
```

In the else block of the IF condition, the previous developer wrote just `return` and it is not even returning anything. If it is not returning `null`, what is the use of having just `return` ?
Since I couldn't understand that particular line, I don't understand how to convert that particular IF condition in Scala.
Could anyone let me know how can I write the same block in Scala in a way that it doesn't impact the code below the first IF-ELSE condition ?

Comment: The method returns void, so nothing _(like **Unit** in Scala)_. That `return` there is just for aborting the execution of the method.

Comment: ok, in that case, how can I break the method execution in Scala instead of using a `return` statement in Scala ?

Comment: Well **Scala** provides different ways to return early including: using `return` _(discouraged but quickly and useful)_, writing your own _(tail)_ recursive function function which you can abort in any moment. Using higher order functions that have an early return like `forall` or `collectFirst`. Or using a **Monad** with short circuit like **Option** or **Either**. - Without understanding more about the code is hard to tell which one would be the best in this case.

Comment: the method signature declares it returns void which is not the same thing as returning null. null is a subtype of everything. in your codebase the purpose of the return is to exit the function

Comment: It's an early exit from a method https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement Scala supports that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915701/is-non-local-return-in-scala-new but it's better to rewrite code so that a method has the only exit point.

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution in this case is to put the second `if` inside the first `if` and remove the `else` part.